# How to compile executable into another file(Not source)

Tags: c, compilation

Say I have the C file in C:/programs/uncompiled and want to compile into C:/programs/executable, is there any way for me to do this in MinGW?

I've tried making an abomination something like

```
gcc -d executable -Wall -o helloworld.exe helloworld.c
```

But this obviously doesn't work as it isn't Java.
Is it just not possible to compile into another file other than where the source file is located? Thanks SO much for any help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a pathname as the `-o` paramerer:

```
gcc -Wall -o C:/programs/executable/helloworld.exe C:/programs/uncompiled/helloworld.c
```

If your current directory is `C:/programs/uncompiled`, you can use a relative path:

```
gcc -Wall -o ../executable/helloworld.exe helloworld.c
```

Answer (score 0):

You just want the exe in another folder? Try

```
gcc -d executable -Wall -o ../executable/helloworld.exe helloworld.c`
```

assuming you're in the source folder. You will probably want to learn how to use `make` at some point, as compiling and linking multiple files by hand quickly gets tedious. A quick example is shown below:

```
SOURCEDIR=src
BUILDDIR=build
CFLAGS=-Wall -Werror -O0 -g
LDFLAGS=-d executable

$(BUILDDIR)/something.exe: $(BUILDDIR)/something.o $(BUILDDIR)/somethingelse.o 
    gcc $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^

$(BUILDDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.c
    gcc $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

You'd want to change the files next to `something.exe` to the names of your `.c` files (with the `.o` extension), and then you'd run `make` to build your project.